# Basic "Get Variable Value" Using GopherJS

Tags: javascript, variables, go, gopherjs

I'm trying to use GopherJS, but I couldn't find documentation about how to use it.

Here's the Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js"
)

func main() {
    t := js.Global.Get("key").Int()
    println(t)
    js.Global.Set("keySet", 4)
}
```

Then I convert it to JS using GopherJS and paste it:

JS code:

```
var key = 3

// Pasted GopherJS Code
"use strict";
(function() {
...
}).call(this);
// End GopherJS Code

console.log(keySet)
```

It prints:

```
0
4
```

Why? It should've printed

```
3
4
```

Here's what I've tried (changing the Go code and re-converting):

```
func main() {
    t := js.Global.Get("key").Float()
    println(t)
    js.Global.Set("keySet", 4)
}
```

prints

```
NaN
4
```

---

```
func main() {
    t := js.Global.Get("key").Int64()
    println(t)
    js.Global.Set("keySet", 4)
}
```

prints

```
typ { '$high': 0, '$low': 0, '$val': [Circular] }
4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js.Global` does not do what you seem to think it does.

The `js.Global` variable is [documented as](https://godoc.org/github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js#Global):

> Global gives JavaScript's global object ("window" for browsers and "GLOBAL" for Node.js).

This means that:

```
js.Global.Get("key")
```

is accessing `window.key` in the browser, or `GLOBAL.key` in Node.js, not a global variable `key`, as you're trying to do.

More generally, if you want standard JS to access GopherJS-generated code you should use the `js.Wrap` method [as documented](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/wiki/JavaScript-Tips-and-Gotchas#tips).

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't very well give you the code you're looking for. It's not very complex, though.